# Метод messages.get (VK API) — Как правильно использовать?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, sdk

Всем доброго времени суток. Первый раз имею дело с API социальных сетей. Пробую использовать ВК API (в данном случае метод [`messages.get`](https://new.vk.com/dev/messages.get)).

Получил `APP_ID`, написал код с клиентской авторизацией и `messages.get`-запросом:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="vk_api_transport"></div>
 <div id="login_button" onclick="VK.Auth.login(authInfo);"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  window.vkAsyncInit = function() {
   VK.init({
    apiId: APP_ID
   });
  };

  function authInfo(response) {
   console.log(response)
   if (response.session) {
    alert('user: ' + response.session.mid);
   } else {
    alert('not auth');
   }
  }
  VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
  VK.UI.button('login_button');

  VK.Api.call('messages.get', {
   fields: 'messages'
  }, function(data) {
   console.log(data)
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
   var el = document.createElement("script");
   el.type = "text/javascript";
   el.src = "//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js";
   el.async = true;
   document.getElementById("vk_api_transport").appendChild(el);
  }, 0);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

В результате в консоли получаю следующее сообщение:

> Access denied: no access to call this method

Подскажите, что я сделал не так и как это исправить, куда смотреть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@t1nk и @Gikas сказали всё правильно: у вашего токена доступа нет соответствующих прав `messages`. Получить эти права можно только для Standalone-приложения, для других типов приложений это всё недоступно (см. [документацию о правах доступа](https://new.vk.com/dev/permissions))

Answer (score 1):

Хм, странно что код вообще отрабатывает - с обращением то к объекту, код которого грузится где-то в хвосте...

Но ладно, вариантов несколько:

1. Не пройдена авторизация, перед вызовом `messages.get`
2. Не выставлены права для приложения для доступа к сообщениям (см. [документацию](https://new.vk.com/dev/messages.get)).

Comment: Права доступа к "messages" вроде доступно только standalone-приложениям. У автора, я так понимаю, не standalone?